# Scrapy - invalid syntax python 2.7

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having an invalid syntax in my code. Thanks in advance for your help!

I've tried to run in Python 3.9 and 3.10 also, but it didn't work.

The code follows below:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector


with open('dataset__petz.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = [
        "Link",
        "Title",
        "Images",
        "Reviews",
        "Average Stars",
        "Description",
        "Price",
    ]
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    total_pages = 7683 // 20
    for page_num in range(total_pages + 1):
        headers = {
            'authority': 'www.petz.com.br',
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
            'accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'referer': 'https://www.petz.com.br/cachorro',
            'accept-language': 'en-PK,en;q=0.9,ur-PK;q=0.8,ur;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,sv;q=0.4,it;q=0.3',
            'cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.53852958.1643655176; ajs_anonymous_id=%226f300057-6c2b-4435-aeb2-64209b1c75ef%22; blueID=767f2efe-82e2-46a4-b53f-b0598a74e307; _scid=f9212b58-afba-46ab-9942-4aed2341831c; _pin_unauth=dWlkPVlXTm1PR1UxTVRrdE1XRmtOaTAwWW1JeUxUazNOak10WXpBd1pqSmpaRFExTXpnMw; _hjSessionUser_257734=eyJpZCI6IjE0YmJhZDZlLWE4ZmEtNWU4MS1hNjY2LTBhMjk5NDRmMDkyMCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDM2NTUxODY2MzgsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; JSESSIONID=097C5726F3743DB8DA56DEC9394CCAA5; petzCarrinho=true; _gid=GA1.3.1987275895.1645062208; _gat=1; ab.storage.sessionId.8160f757-f57f-4d17-9cfb-44c82d5e8f64=%7B%22g%22%3A%2256dad591-fbb9-58ca-b56f-16301eedcaa0%22%2C%22e%22%3A1645062242208%2C%22c%22%3A1645062210438%2C%22l%22%3A1645062212208%7D; _uetsid=03d15a308f9311ec8c0761ae408d793e; _uetvid=03887a2082c711ec88b9d507def7682c; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjSession_257734=eyJpZCI6IjliY2Q3YWE1LTIyZWMtNGY1OS04MmM4LWViNzYwYmFiZjdlYSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDUwNjIyMTM3NTYsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; cto_bundle=OjK6yF9rYUQwazkzZ1hqbGQ0TVVhc1ZINEtqUkZrenI2cVJTRG5oRW1XWmZDc3JBOG9tZ1FEblFqYnh4VVZTTzhpTlBiSmU0cVdjWmo1SmI5NFBnY1pRVWNKT2htbUxqOHVnWGh4eld3OVdzRFBwcERJdVVkUzVTVkZ2Nm5XZyUyQmRtekNaM05kY3dwVENacUJmMSUyQjBXRnIlMkZnQnclM0QlM0Q; _clck=1jfl8ab|1|ez2|0; _clsk=yj3l8j|1645062215905|1|1|a.clarity.ms/collect; _sctr=1|1645038000000; AWSALB=F7AuR70LF27a5QDYcZ/a3VpvBix2n+zWGKxBvpe1n0V2Lu3LYXtzsAY9buKvrZ50OUucjSRaEdOD2kHurmAO9MZ7Q0jEnQqG3AD+XaW3H0fWTfODTk3SS2VrdZ37; AWSALBCORS=F7AuR70LF27a5QDYcZ/a3VpvBix2n+zWGKxBvpe1n0V2Lu3LYXtzsAY9buKvrZ50OUucjSRaEdOD2kHurmAO9MZ7Q0jEnQqG3AD+XaW3H0fWTfODTk3SS2VrdZ37',
        }

        params = (
            ('page', page_num),
            ('np', '385'),
            ('total', '7683'),
            ('view', ''),
            ('sort', '0'),
            ('cor', '0'),
            ('pi', ''),
            ('pf', ''),
        )

        r = requests.get('https://www.petz.com.br/cachorro', headers=headers, params=params)
        
        response = Selector(text=r.text)
        
        products = response.xpath('//li[@class="liProduct"]')
        if products == []:
            break
        for product in products[:2]:
            link = product.xpath('.//a[@id="produto-href"]/@href').get()
            product_request = requests.get(url=f'https://www.petz.com.br{link}', headers=headers)
            
            product_resp = Selector(text=product_request.text)
            product_images = product_resp.xpath('//div[@class="sp-wrap"]/a/@href').getall()
            
            data = {
                "Link": product_request.url,
                "Title": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text())').get(),
                "Images": ", ".join(product_images),
                "Reviews": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/text())').get(),
                "Average Stars": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/text())').get(),
                "Description": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@itemprop="description"])').get(),
                "Price": product_resp.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="current-price-left"]/strong/text())').get(),
            }
            
            csv_writer.writerow(data)
            print(data)
            
            for image_link in product_images:
                image_resp = requests.get(image_link)
                with open(os.path.join("images", image_link.split('/')[-1]), 'wb') as image_downloader:
                    image_downloader.write(image_resp.content)

import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv('dataset__petz.csv')
csv_file.to_excel('dataset__petz.xlsx', index=False)
```

The error **File "main.py", line 57
product_request = requests.get(url=f'https://www.petz.com.br{link}', headers=headers)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: "I've tried to run in Python 3.9 and 3.10 also, but it didn't work" - please provide the exact, complete error traceback in this case. Code written for recent versions of Python, like this one, generally won't run without modifications under old versions like Python 2.7 (which reached end of life more than 2 years ago btw...)

Comment: In Python 3.9 and 3.10 it simply doesn't do anything. The terminal restarts without any traceback error

Comment: If `products == []` you `break` from the loop. If this happens during the first iteration it might look as if the program does nothing. Verify the program flow with a debugger - or use `print` to show the value of some crucial variables.

Comment: F-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. In earlier versions they give a syntax error. This code will not give a syntax error in Python 3.9. It may very well give a different error, but not the one you report. And as a beginner, you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.

Comment: Hey Boar! Thanks for your enlightenment. I've just tried 2.7 version because it didn't work on Python 3.9 and 3.10. Any idea what could be wrong with the code?

Comment: *I've just tried 2.7 version because it didn't work on Python 3.9 and 3.10.* That is not a good idea. Most tutorial material will present Python 3 code and if you run it in Python 2 you will simply get messages that are both baffling and irrelevant, as in this case. @Matthias has already provided a pointer on how to approach the problem. If the program produces no output then that is because `print(data)` never executes. If it is not executing, then either `products == []` is `True`, or `products[:2]` is an empty list. Start by putting `print(len(products))` after the call to `.xpath()`.

Comment: If products == [] you break from the loop. This has fix everything!

Thanks a lot guys, i love you all